# Django Upload Images

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-uploads

I have been trying to work with the uploading features of Django but I just can't seem to get it to work. My form already contains `enctype="multipart/form-data"` so that can't be the issue. Anyways here's what im working with:

This is my model

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    """ This represents a Photo
    """
    caption = models.CharField(_("caption"), max_length=100, null=True,
        blank=True, unique=True)
    image = ValidateImageField(
    upload_to='uploaded_photos/Published/%Y/%B/%d/',
    content_types=['image/jpeg', 'image/gif', 'image/png'],
    max_upload_size= settings.FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE
    )
    source = models.URLField(_("source"), null=True, blank=True)
    status = models.CharField(_("status"), max_length=1, choices=STATUS_CHOICES,    default='H')
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(_("date_added"), auto_now_add=True)
    date_modified = models.DateTimeField(_("date_modified"), auto_now=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(_("slug"), max_length=50, unique=True)
    extra_info = models.TextField(_("extra_info"), null=True, blank=True)
```

This is my form:

```
class UploadImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Photo
        field = ('image', 'caption', 'source', 'extra_info',)
        exclude = ('status','slug',)
```

This is my view:

```
def submit_image(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid:
            form.save()
        return redirect('photos.views.upload_success')

    form = UploadImageForm()
    return render(request,'photos/upload.html', {
        'form': form
    })
```

I have already tried using the chunks method as shown in the djangodocs and that too doesn't work. Could there be a problem with my code, if so I would be grateful if someone can point it out. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure that your form is just invalid (for example there is no required `slug` provided). But you don't handle this, redirecting to success page anyway. Also you've forgotten parentheses after `is_valid`, so it will be always `True`. Correct view will be something like this:

```
def submit_image(request):
    form = UploadImageForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('photos.views.upload_success')

    return render(request,'photos/upload.html', {
        'form': form
    })
```